# What are those Webpack loaders test property symbols

Tags: webpack

I am new to webpack and going through webpack documentation here https://webpack.js.org/loaders/:

And I happened to find this:

`test: /\.css$/,`

Just wondering what are those front/back slashes and $ symbol meant for?

Comment: Those are regular expressions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: /RegExpr/ -> for example /\.css$/ reads as -> dot css end, so it will match something like: myFile.css

Comment: understood..thank you all